# MySQL sql ignoring WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have the following problem - I am coding an e-commerce website, that has promotions for a certain period of time. When time elapses promotion changes its corresponding database `active` value to 0. When I check for promotions the first condition is that `active=1`, but at some cases MySQL is ignoring it.

Here is an example of my most recent problem:

```
    $productPromotion = $db->getResults('*', TABLE_PROMO, "active = '1' 
AND (discount_subject = 'all_orders' 
OR discount_subject_product = ".$values['product']['id'].") 
OR (discount_subject = 'category' 
AND discount_subject_category = ".$categoryId[0] . ") ORDER BY id ASC");
```

`$db->getResult` is a custom function that takes 3 parameters - What, Table and Where.

The problem is that it is returning promotions that are already expired and have active=0. Where is the problem with my sql?

Comment: MySQL cannot see your PHP code. What's the actual SQL query you are generating?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add brackets arround  `or`

```
 $productPromotion = $db->getResults('*', TABLE_PROMO, "active = '1' 
      AND 
     ((discount_subject = 'all_orders' OR discount_subject_product = ".$values['product']['id'].")
        OR (discount_subject = 'category' AND discount_subject_category     = ".$categoryId[0] . ")) ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Also learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection